# Delphi - check if hint is currently displayed

Tags: delphi, hint

My hint tooltip appear on 3000 ms. 
Need to check when it start and stop displaying for certain label.
In other words is that possible to determine when it appear and disappear?

Comment: What mechanism are you using to display the hints? Is your project VCL or FMX? If you provided a [mcve] then there'd be no possibility of us making incorrect guesses and wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Simple VCL example: `examplelabel.ShowHint := True; examplelabel.Hint := 'Test';`

Comment: I found that showing is possible to get but no hiding? [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnHint)

Comment: `Application.OnShowHint` is your friend.

Comment: thx, problem is that I need second friend and cannot find handler for that, because I also need to know when Hint disapear.

Comment: [THintWindow Class](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_THintWindow.html) Using it you are able to control anything related to hints in your app.

Comment: @abelisto There are many many ways to show hints, the question doesn't state which is in use, hence the need for clarification. Guessing is not constructive.